# Тип меню Битрикс

Tags: меню, битрикс

есть компонент "меню" в битрикс.
нужно так изменить его, что бы при редактировании/добавлении пункта меню, была возможность добавить картинку, указать к ней путь(я так понимаю это самый простой вариант)
после эта картинка идет и вставляется под сам пункт меню.
в общем нужно добавить еще одну ячейку на странице редактирования/добавления пункта меню.
как это сделать не понимаю.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Перейди на редактирование меню в Панели управления, там есть дополнительные поля "Параметры"...

[image: img]

```
.template.php
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
<?if (!empty($arResult)):?>

    <?foreach($arResult as $arItem):?>
        **<?if($arItem["PARAMS"]["RED"]){?>
            <dd class="red"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><img src="<?=$arItem["PARAMS"]["RED"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></dd>**
        <?}else{?>
            <dd><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></dd>
        <?}?>
    <?endforeach?>
    <dd class="fill"></dd>
<?endif?>
```

**Обновление**

Можно костыль сделать, то есь в название прописать "Просто `эклибрис#/upload/images.png`"

А в .template.php

```
$text=explode('#',$arItem["TEXT"]);

<a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$text[1] ? '<img src="'.$text[1].'"/>' : '';?><?=$text[0]?></a>
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ.
в принципе это решение подходит, но оно очень не удобное.
я бы хотел, что бы можно было обойтись без доп.массива "парамерты"
я бы хотел внести изменения в сам массив arItem т.е. добавить в него элемент, что бы не приходилось каждый раз идти в панель управления, т.е. добавить к ячейкам ["LINK"] и ["TEXT"] ячейку ["IMAGE"].

Comment: я хочу добавить элементы, а не просто их подправить:)
решение сложное и долгое, и очень нужное:)